# Deploy Java Web Application and MySQL database in the cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans

my issue is that I've been developing a Java Web app in Netbeans 7.2, which I've used Hibernate and JSF Facelets to communicate and show the data from a MySQL database deployed in my local server (localhost).

But now, I want to deploy both (my java web app and mysql database) in the cloud in a web server, or something but I don't know even how to start this. I've seen something about Google App Engine, but I didn't get the idea, and many others...

I just need to deploy my app to give access to other people to use my web app.

Comment: What web container is your web app running in: Glassfish? Tomcat?

Comment: The web app is running on Tomcat. I just want to let my workmates access to that web app and make queries there.

Answer (score 0):

Google Appengine is a Framework. 
its not webserver where you can deploy your app as on your local machine.

what you are looking for is 
Amazon EC2

Google ComputeEngine

OpenShift

and others...... (to many to list them all)

most of them are not free. 
some like openshift are if you dont need much resources.

there you can install the server you need, (its just like a remote server) 
and deploy your app to.

Comment: I don't know how to do it... U_U I'm working with Netbeans + Hibernate + JSF and Openshift for example works with Eclipse and etc. Moreover I need to upload a mysql database connected with my web app through hibernate....

Comment: Actually, for the op basic neeeds [GAE default hosting](https://appengine.google.com/) and [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql) may fit the bill just fine... He can [deploy his projects with a command line tool](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine), no need for the extra burden of managing instances.

Comment: Good tutorials on [setting up a a GAE Project with JSF support](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-20/configuring-javaserver-faces-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine) and [setting up Hibernate with Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate). When you get it to run in your machine, just [create an application in GAE](https://appengine.google.com/start/createapp?), update `appengine-web.xm` with your application id, run `appcfg update` and you are done.

Comment: GAE is much more a web server (think Tomcat or the web-part of Glassfish) than a framework. You can run a plain Java web app (no EJB, JMS) on GAE without using any GAE-specific code. I wouldn't recommend someone EC2 or GCE if he doesn't even understand GAE.

Comment: GAE is running a jetty
yeah thats a point, but i assume when you are able to setup a tomcat / jboss (wich have tomcat as webcontainer) and mysql on your local machine, it should be possible todo on any other server. 
and before using GAE you schould really understand this.
and then you need to start GAE, even you dont use GAE APIs, its different then tomcat, because of initial request, loading dependency and so on....
so i would recommend  to checkout a "simple" provider, where deployement and setup is done with webinterface. learn it and go further,

Comment: a list to compare existing solutions is here:
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/platform-as-a-service-paas-for-cloud-applications-scalable-cluster-of-services

when i remember right jelastic have an easy webinterface. 
and as hint, use sublimetext for coding, because without all the IDE features, you learn faster how the things works